# Count number of features in a geopackage and write to a file

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, geopackage

I'm tasked to create a simple catalogue of 2000+ geopackages, and hope there is a way to do that with QGIS.

The idea is to batch run over all these geopackages and write the following to a CSV file;

file name, number of features, geometry type, srid, bbox

for eg, a CSV entry like this;

countour.gpkg, 1876, multipolyline, 4326, bbox
..
..

Did anyone had such a requirement in the past? It will be great if this can be done using QGIS processing toolbox as a batch process.

EDIT
There are 2000+ gpkg with one table in each file. Add to that, each geopackage has strictly one table with one geometry type only..

Comment: @BERA, thanks. there are 2000+ gpkg with one table in each file. Add to that, each geopackage has strictly one table with one geometry type only. If this helps.

Comment: `ogrinfo` and a for loop will do this

Comment: Feels like a small SQL exercise. Table name, geometry type name and srs_id are in the gpkg_geometry_columns table. Min/max x and y (and srs_id again) are in the gpkg_contents. If GeoPackages have been created with GDAL the feature count is in a non-standard ogr_gpkg_contents table. Otherwise run "select count() from table_name". Nothing of that requires spatial capabilities so any SQLite client will do. Only if the geometry type in the gpkg_geometry_columns has been written as generic "geometry" you must run spatial SQL and find the real geometry type. Doable with ogrinfo and `-sql`.

Comment: thanks, Ian Turton. Sure that's useful for many of my work.

Comment: thanks user30184, looks like it is a long way for me. Not so conversant with SQL yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had done something similar with python. The script loops recursive through the directories starting from the startdir and then opens each geopackage and reads the gpkg_contents table - containing geometry type, extent, CRS, date and so on, the second query selects the number of features. The script works on the first featuretable in a geopackage only, may be you have to adjust this to your needs:

```
import sqlite3
import glob 
import csv
root_dir = 'c:/startdir/'
result = root_dir + 'gpkg_result.csv'
with open(result, 'w', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for filename in glob.iglob(root_dir + '**/*.gpkg', recursive=True):
        con = sqlite3.connect(filename)
        with con:
            cursor = con.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM gpkg_contents;")
            l1 = list(cursor.fetchall()[0])
            cursor.execute("SELECT Count(*) FROM {};".format(l1[0]))
            l2 = list(cursor.fetchall()[0])
            cursor.execute("SELECT geometry_type_name FROM gpkg_geometry_columns")
            l3 = list(cursor.fetchall()[0])
            wr.writerow(l1+l2+l3)
```

Comment: thank you very much. The scrips work like a charm and precisely what I wanted it. hugs.

Comment: HI eurojam, not able to figure out how I can change the code so it writes the "geometry type" in the csv. Looking for a way since that's one of the headaches; to identify if the gpkg is a point, line or area.

Comment: Hi Garry, you are right, I missed that. I added one more sql statement with the geometry_type_name. Now it should work like expected.

Comment: Hi eurojam, thank you very much. Yes, it works great now. :)

Answer (score 3):

### A pyqgis script

It handles other formats (shp, tab, gpkg, geojson...) all formats that ogr can handle

But it does not handle sublayers

```
import os
import csv
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

FOLDER = 'c:/folder/to/scan'
RESULT = 'c:/folder/metadata.csv'

def scan_directory(directory, extension=('.tab', '.shp', '.gpkg')):
    """return the list of files that matche the extension

    Args:
        directory (str): the folder to scan
        extension (tuple, optional): the extension. Defaults to ('.tab', '.shp', '.gpkg').
    """
    extension = tuple(map(str.lower, extension))
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, topdown=False):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.lower().endswith(extension):
                yield(root, filename, os.path.join(root, filename))

def get_metadata(layer):
    """Return metadata

    Args:
        layer ([ogr vectorlayer]): [Not sublayer]

    Returns:
        metadata: (name, comment, encoding....)
    """
    name = layer.name()
    comment = layer.dataComment()
    encoding = layer.dataProvider().encoding()
    datasource = layer.publicSource()
    feature_count = layer.featureCount()
    geom_type = geom_wkbtype = crs  = extent = None
    if layer.isSpatial():
        geom_type = layer.geometryType()
        if geom_type <0 or geom_type > QgsWkbTypes.NullGeometry:
            print(f'{layer} invalid geometry type')
        else:
            geom_wkbtype = QgsWkbTypes.displayString(layer.wkbType())
            geom_type = QgsWkbTypes.geometryDisplayString(geom_type)
        if layer.crs().isValid():
            crs = layer.crs().userFriendlyIdentifier(
                QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.FullString )
        extent=layer.extent().toString()
    return (name, comment, encoding, geom_type, 
        geom_wkbtype, crs, extent, feature_count, datasource)
    

with open(RESULT, 'w', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(['name', 'comment', 'encoding',
        'geom_type', 'geom_wkbtype', 'crs', 'extent', 'feature_count','datasource'])
    
    for root, filename, path in scan_directory(FOLDER):
        layer = QgsVectorLayer(path, filename,'ogr')
        if not layer.isValid():
            print(f'{layer.name()} is not valid')
            continue
        wr.writerow(get_metadata(layer))
```

Code available : https://gist.github.com/42a6b3ab8e1069e3e0523ca90c361aaa

Comment: Hi lejedi76. Thank you very much. This variant works great as well. I have two scripts to handle the work. I noticed that your script can be run on shp files too. So, definitely will be useful. hugs and cheers.